# XCode Cloud Build Error when deploying to cloud run

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-cloud

XCode Cloud Build Error

```
Check that a scheme called APP exists in APP.xcworkspace, is shared, and is committed to the 'develop' branch, and that this branch has been pushed to your remote repository.
```

How can I handle it?

Comment: How did you set it up? What did you do? What have you already tried to resolve this? What is the configuration you are using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly the scheme, the bundle identifier, the app development team should be correctly set on your Xcode.
2. The bundle identifier should exist on the related AppStore-connect account.
3. When creating workflow, same environment/scheme should be addressed. you can edit the workflow and make sure that every thing is the same as defined on your Xcode.
4. ***The branch that is added to **start condition**, must exists on your repo.***
5. While finalising the creation of the workflow, App Store connect should reconnect to GitHub. In this way it can access the branch and build it.

This documentation might help:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-start-conditions